# Brute force attack expected running time

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, collision-resistance, brute-force-attack, complexity

I am a bit confused about the expected running times of brute force attacks on different cryptosystems.

So let's assume a key size of $2^n$ bits.

1. Symmetric key cryptography:

   $E(brute)$ = $2^{n-1}\cdot$ comparisons time

   So if I understood correctly I need to generate all the possible $2^n$ keys to find the "right" key for sure. Now taken into account the definition of Expected Value of a random variable $X$, that can take the value $x_i$ with $p_i$: $E[X] = \sum p_i \times x_i$. So in our case we can say that $k=2^n$ and $E[X] = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{k} = \frac{k+1}{2} \approx 2^{n-1}$.
2. Cryptographic hashes

   Following the birthday paradox analogy and approximating the required time we end up with $E[X] = \sqrt{2^n} = 2^{n/2}$ comparisons.

My confusion comes from public key cryptography and from ECC: in [this post](http://www.embedded.com/design/safety-and-security/4396040/An-Introduction-to-Elliptic-Curve-Cryptography) ECC is nicely described, but it says that on average you must guess $2^{n/2}$ keys. I don't really understand where this number comes from as you are not searching for a collision as in the case of hashes, but for an exact match.

Comment: You're confused. Brute force on a $2^{128}$ key takes $2^{128}$ time. Anything else is no longer brute force.

Comment: I was talking about the expected time of brute force.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ECC takes about $2^{n/2}$ time to break because there are smarter ways to attack it than literally trying each possible key separately.

With AES, the best known-attack is to try a key, and see if it works.  If it doesn't, all you've learned is that that specific key wasn't it, only $2^{n}-1$ more to go...

However, with ECC, there are other methods.  For ECC, in general, a public key gives us two elliptic curve points $G$ and $P$; to break it, we need to find an integer $k$ such that $kG = P$ (where $kG$ is point multiplication).

Now, there are $q$ possible values of $k$ (where $q \approx 2^{n}$ is a large prime that depends on the curve); however here is a smarter way to attack it:

- Compute a value $r \approx \sqrt{q}$
- Generate the $r$ values $P-0G, P-1G, P-2G, P-3G, ..., P-(r-1)G$.  This takes $O(r) = O(\sqrt{q}) = O(2^{n/2})$ time.
- Generate the $r$ values $0rG, 1rG, 2rG, 3rG, ..., (r-1)rG$.  This also takes $O(r) = O(\sqrt{q}) = O(2^{n/2})$ time.
- Scan through the two lists for a value in common; if we see that $P-iG = jrG$, (for two integers $i$, $j$) then we have $P = (jr+i)G$, and that solves it.  This always succeeds if $r \ge \sqrt{q}$, and this takes $O(2^{n/2})$ time if we use an appropriate hash table.

Total time taken: $O(2^{n/2})$.

This isn't the only way to solve the problem this quickly (there's also Pollard's Rho, which doesn't involve huge tables), however this is the easiest to explain.

Comment: "With AES, the best known-attack is to try a key, and see if it works." - If I've understood [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/cryptanalysis/aesbc.pdf) correctly, I think Dmitry Khovratovich would disagree

Comment: I also read, that the order of $G$ must be prime. Why is that?

Comment: @Pio: it doesn't **have** to be prime, but if it's not, it makes like easier on the attacker.  If the Order of $G$ ($q$ in the above text) is $rs$, then the attacker can solve $k'rG = rP$ and $k''sG = sP$ (total of O($\sqrt{max(r,s)})$ time), and then recombine $k'$ and $k''$ into the original $k$, solving the problem faster than he could if $q$ was prime.

Comment: Our results just show how to try each key faster, but it is still $O(2^n)$, just the constant inside big-O decreases. @poncho is correct here.